# Unable to link FFI library in Haskell

Tags: haskell, gcc, sdl, ghc, ffi

I have the following source file (sdl.hs):

```
module Main where

import Graphics.UI.SDL.Mixer.Music
import Graphics.UI.SDL.Mixer
import Graphics.UI.SDL

main = loadMUS ""
```

I try the following:

```
ghc --make sdl.hs
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\SDL-mixer-0.6.1\ghc-7.6.3/libHSSDL-mixer-0.6.1.a(Music.o):fake:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `Mix_FreeMusic' 
...
```

It gives me a few dozen of these errors. I have tried everything I could (update, clean install, 
and Google) but I know next to nothing about FFI in Haskell and how it is supposed to work.

Some extra info:

```
c:\>gcc --version
realgcc.exe (GCC) 4.5.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

c:\>ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3

c:\>cabal install sdl sdl-mixer
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
SDL-0.6.4
SDL-mixer-0.6.1
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

Attempting to start anything SDL related from GHCi gives the following:

```
Prelude> import Graphics.UI.SDL.Mixer.Music
Prelude Graphics.UI.SDL.Mixer.Music> loadMUS ""
Loading package SDL-0.6.4 ... <interactive>: Unknown PEi386 section name `.idata$4' (while processing: C:\sdl\SDL-1.2.15\lib\libSDL.dll.a)
ghc.exe: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.6.3 for i386-unknown-mingw32):
        loadArchive "C:\\sdl\\SDL-1.2.15\\lib\\libSDL.dll.a": failed

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
```

I found [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3658) which seems related but it has been around for a while now and there is no hope in sight of windows getting the proposed `fix'.

Comment: Does the file C:\sdl\SDL-1.2.15\lib\libSDL.dll.a exist?

Comment: Oh if only it were that simple. It does indeed exist. The C libraries are 'installed' correctly - I can compile and run a simple program in C++. This is an issue with Haskell itself. If I try to compile a slightly different program which uses a different function, GHC will complain about a different set of missing defintions, which seems to indicate that it finds the library but the linker doesn't like the format of it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using Cabal, rather than invoking GHC directly, as it streamlines these things a bit more.  But that's out of scope here. :)

The solution to this particular issue is generally to list the C libraries on the GHC command line, as in:

> ghc --make -lSDL -lSDL_mixer sdl.hs

I don't use Windows (or dynamic linking with GHC), so I don't know if this command works; it's just a thought.

Comment: GHC finds the location of the libraries. And I would hope a program with a single function call could compile without a cabal file.

Comment: Well, actually, your transcripts above show that GHC is finding the _Haskell_ libraries.  My suspicion is that it simply doesn't know - because GHC is a low-level tool as far as its invocation goes, unlike Cabal - that it needs to include the _C_ libraries which correspond to the Haskell ones.  That is, when the Haskell libraries are building, Cabal knows to pass the C libraries in - but since you're not using Cabal, nothing knows to pass them in now that you're building an executable with the libraries.